# How is the route "/authentication/login" wired to "_LoginPartial.cshtml"?

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created an app via `dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted --auth Individual`. It worked as expected. I then edited this app in a few ways and now it's broken. `/authentication/login` now only displays a blank page:
[image]

And I notice that, in my Server project, I'm not hitting _LoginPartial.cshtml breakpoints [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/ProjectTemplates/Web.ProjectTemplates/content/ComponentsWebAssembly-CSharp/Server/Areas/Identity/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml#L8) or [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/ProjectTemplates/Web.ProjectTemplates/content/ComponentsWebAssembly-CSharp/Server/Areas/Identity/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml#L15), where I previously was.

- Y problem: I'm not hitting breakpoints in `_LoginPartial.cshtml` -- what mechanism "wires" the route `authentication/login` to that file?
- X problem: I only get blank pages on any attempt to authenticate.

Comment: I understand that I can solve the X problem by starting fresh and retracing my steps. I'm asking a targeted question (which may be misplaced) in hopes of better understanding the relationship between the Client and Server projects while also solving the problem. I hope I haven't done anything wrong.

Comment: For posterity, the breaking change was Rider Code Cleanup. Investigating further.

Answer (score 0):

The "wiring" I was looking for was this using directive:

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Rider marks this as "not required" and will remove it on Code Cleanup.

Comment: I'm learning how Razor components work so I don't understand the magic behind this yet, but at any rate this is the answer.

Comment: Bug report for posterity: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-56916